# Liquibase use a changelog outside of my jar file

Tags: java, jar, liquibase, changelog

I developed an app that uses Liquibase and built a jar file.

I was wondering if it is possible to use a changelog file that is outside of the jar file , like for example:

```
-Folder
--jar file
--changelogFile
```

I know that Liquibase removed the option to use an absolute path , so is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer. If you are using the Java liquibase Api just use a ResourceAccessor

```
ResourceAccessor accessor= new FileSystemResourceAccessor("C:\\Users\\demo\\Documents\\Migrations");
return new Liquibase(changelog, accessor, connection);
```